Stop VisualStudio 2022 from erasing the period in intelliSense AutoCompletion
I work on Visual studio 2022 (Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.10.3 ) and intellisense autocomplete erases the period. How can i have it not erase the period (or add it automatically after it is erased) ?
edit: Just noticed that on another project (same VS version of course), auto-completion works properly ! Is there a way to copy whatever settings that project has onto my own ? Could I even see the differences listed ?
For example, whenever I am typing my code and type in an object (such "products") and type the period/fullstop sign (".") right afterwards, the suggestions for completing the code appear, such as "length", "push", "map", "foreach", "join" etc. I can then press the arrow keys to navigate along the list's terms. If I then press Enter or Tab, it selects and types its selection onto my code.
It should be typing it right at my cursor's position, and this means after the full stop / period sign ("."). Instead, it deletes the period sign and writes right at the end of my previously typed word, creating a monster of a term (such as "productslength", instead of "products.length").
This is how it looks with the intellicode suggestion... and
this is how it looks after I press enter or tab or double-click on the auto-completion.

Sample code used in project
let products = []; /* Store fetched products globally. */
async function initialize_Data() {
products = await fetchOnlineData(url_Products);
}
function CreateProductsListCardsHTML() {
products.forEach((product, index) => {
const cardHTML = CreateProductCardHTML(product);
productCards.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', cardHTML);
})
}
.



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Just noticed that on another project (same VS version of course), auto-completion works properly.

Are both projects opened with the same VS instance installed on your machine?

From looking at your description, it seems the intellisense does not work. For this issue, here are suggestions you can check:
1.Did you install three-party expansions like ReSharper? If yes, please navigate to Editor->Completing Characters and set Enter Key/Tab Key to Inserts or disable this extension and switch to visual studio native intellisense.

2.Please try to  reset all settings and restart you visual studio.
For more information, please read Reset all settings
3.If your VS is not the latest, please update your VS to the latest version with Visual Studio Installer.
If the issue persists, you can provide more information about your issue:

What is the type/language of your project ?
What is the version of your VS?
The screenshot of your productslength

UPDATE

Is there a way to copy whatever settings that project has onto my own ? Could I even see the differences listed?

You can use a Template to reuse the same settings. Open that project, go to Project->Export Template and follow the wizard to create a template that includes your settings.

Then create a project with the exported template.

If you open the both projects with the same VS instance installed on your machine, auto-completion works properly in another project, please try to delete .vs folder in your project and reload it to see if the issue persists.
Hope it can help.

Thank you for your suggestions. I followed them but unfortunately, they did not help.
I have no extensions.
I reset all settings and restarted my visual studio.
My VS is the latest.
More info :

My project is as follows :

net8.0



As I wrote above, Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.10.3.
I updated my post with screenshots.


I tried to reproduce the issue in the same environment but with no luck. From looking at your screenshots, is products an array as it has length/push/etc methods? Could  you share sample code about products?

Yes, and I just did. Also added an "edit" comment about how auyto-completion works as intended on other projects.

I copied your sample code into my js file and the  IntelliSense works fine. See the Test result. Does the intellisense work normal if you run VS in a safe mode? devenv /safemode  Have you  modified any VS-related registry  keys recently?
